# jQuery animate vertical-align

Tags: jquery, css

I have some content vertically aligned in the middle. At the click of a button, I would like said content to change to `vertical-align: top` but animate as it does so (slide up). It seems this doesn't work though:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">Hello World</div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="myButton" value="No Animation" />
<input type="button" id="myButton2" value="Animation" />
```

**CSS**

```
#container { width: 500px; height: 400px; background: #eee; }
#container:before { content: ''; display: inline-block; width: 1px; height: 100%; vertical-align: middle; background: red; }
#content { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; background: lime; }
```

**JS**

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
  $('#content').css('vertical-align', 'top');
});

$('#myButton2').click(function(){
  $('#content').animate({ 'vertical-align': 'top' }, 500);
});
```

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/arazun/5/edit)

Comment: How do you suppose jQuery should animate the value `"top"` ? Only numbers can be animated!

Comment: I guess I hadn't really thought about how animations work, are they always number based then? I guess I just expected it to work out position A and position B and then work it's magic in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't animate `vertical-align`. With very few exceptions, the animate function only works on numeric values. From the jQuery [animate() docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value

As a workaround, you could set the `top` position of the content dynamically, then animate that:

```
var content = $('#content'),
    contentHeight = content.height();
    containerHeight = $('#container').height()
;

content.css("top", containerHeight/2 - contentHeight/2)

$('#myButton').click(function () {
    content.css('top', 0);
});

$('#myButton2').click(function () {
    content.animate({
        'top': 0
    }, 500);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KEDvY/1)**

Comment: Thanks for the help, I had no idea animate relied on numeric values so much. I didn't quite do your solution (central content changes dynamically and CBA to have an event listener to update the vertical alignment all the time) so instead I just add some negative top margin to push it up a bit.

Comment: cool. any idea how to do this with the content of a table cell?

Comment: Hey @spy :) probably best to ask this as its own question, you'll have a lot more luck getting an answer that way. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can now animate vertical-align if you use a measurement!

[vertical-align values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

set your vertical-align to something like a % or a px and include a transition on that.

Or using jquery, apply a class that contains a css keyframe like so:

```css
.item5, .item6 {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.item5 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #03A9F4;
}
.item6 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #ff5722;

}

.item6:after {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
    -webkit-animation: move 2s infinite alternate;
     -moz-animation: move 2s infinite alternate;
       -o-animation: move 2s infinite alternate;
          animation: move 2s infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move { from { vertical-align: 0% } to { vertical-align: 100% }  }
   @-moz-keyframes move { from { vertical-align: 0% } to { vertical-align: 100% }  }
     @-o-keyframes move { from { vertical-align: 0% } to { vertical-align: 100% }  }
        @keyframes move { from { vertical-align: 0% } to { vertical-align: 100% }  }
```

```html
<div class="item5">1</div>
<div class="item6">2</div>
```

I'm not sure of the browser support though!